One class text classification for open-ended survey questions
I have a specific text analysis problem, and hope someone can point me in the direction of a good approach. I have three corpuses consisting of short documents (open-ended survey questions). One is a "baseline" corpus, and I would like to estimate which of the other two is most similar to it. Ideally, I would be able to do this at the document level, so that I get a statistic showing how likely it is that each document belongs to the "baseline" corpus.
My initial thought is that this is a one class text classification problem. As I understand it, this approach helps identify documents that are outliers with respect to the baseline corpus. One concern I have is that the corpuses I would like to compare to the baseline are topically similar to it. I expect that broadly the same themes will be present in the documents of both corpuses, but that the ferquency with which certain themes are mentioned will vary a fair bit. I worry that merely identifying the number of outliers in each corpus is not discriminating enough. Is there another approach that makes sense?
